# Android realm, app uninstall

Tags: android, realm

I have a simple android app with a realm db/2 tables.

When I uninstall my application, all the realm databases/tables are deleted from my app, or not?

Comment: what about if you save a file inside your app folder, it remains or not while uninstalling?

Comment: I think the file is not deleting, but the realm is yes!:)

Comment: When you uninstall the application, your /data/data/com.example.app folder should be erased. If you're specifically opening the Realm on the external storage (and not inside of your internal storage dedicated data folder as per context.getFilesDir()), then the Realm file will not be removed.

The Realm.getDefaultInstance() and Realm.getInstance(Context) calls open the Realm in getFilesDir(), which means it should be deleted along with the application.

Comment: If it's opened in the internal data directory `getFilesDir()` which is the default, then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, **yes**. The database and tables are deleted on uninstall.

However, there exists cases when they are not deleted.

Gotten from https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2992

> When you uninstall the application, your /data/data/com.example.acme
>   folder should be erased. If you're specifically opening the Realm on
>   the external storage (and not inside of your internal storage
>   dedicated data folder as per context.getFilesDir()), then the Realm
>   file will not be removed.
>
> The Realm.getDefaultInstance() and Realm.getInstance(Context) calls
>   open the Realm in getFilesDir(), which means it should be deleted
>   along with the application.
>
> Maybe you're being a victim of the new Android's auto-backup feature?